# How to cycle API query + array output PHP

Tags: php, arrays, cycle

I am newbie in PHP. I want to export some data from website API, I have script with query and JSON response, but there are about 20 similar queries, and I guess I can make this script much simpler with loops, but really do not know how to. I also want to insert the results into a table.

Sample:

```html
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/clonex');
$json = $response->getBody();
$data = json_decode($json);
print "CloneX: ";
print_r($data->collection->stats->floor_price);

$client2 = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response2 = $client2->request('GET', 'https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/the-solaverse-sola-stars');
$json2 = $response2->getBody();
$data2 = json_decode($json2);
print "<br />SolaVerse: ";
print_r($data2->collection->stats->floor_price);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it - put the names in an array

```
<?php

define('BASE_URL','https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/');
$names = ['clonex','the-solaverse-sola-stars'];
foreach ($names as $n) {
        $json = file_get_contents(BASE_URL.$n);
        $data = json_decode($json);
        if (isset($data->collection->stats->floor_price)) {
                echo $n.' '.$data->collection->stats->floor_price.PHP_EOL;
        }
}
```

Comment: Just what I needed! Thank you!)